# Jquery Cycle not working in IE

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

I'm running into an issue with the Jquery Cycle plugin working in IE. It works great in Firefox and Chrome but in IE all the images in the slideshow just stack below and none of the controls work.

Anyone have any ideas as to what might be going on?

Here is the site:  www.clayhouse.tv

FOUND THE ANSWER... I MUST BE BLIND. ALL I NEEDED TO DO WAS ADD OVERFLOW:HIDDEN TO THE CONTAINER.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of HTML errors. I'd definitely go through and correct those errors. If the problem still persists after that I'd be shocked. I never ran into a problem with cycle in IE.

[The Validator Results](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.clayhouse.tv%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)

Most importantly the duplicate ID issues.

Comment: Thanks Bill, I've been going through some clean-up on the code while figuring this out. Thanks for posting the validator results though, I've still got a lot left before the site is ready to go.